# Document generation using Docusign from Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have a pdf template which is editable form which contains input form, tabs and buttons and I want it to be uploaded in Salesforce and upon click of a button on a record then record values have to be merge on the pdf and download it, and also the existing functionality like input field, tabs and buttons on pdf should work as usual. Can Docusign achieve this functionality, if so please let me know the process how to proceed.

I created a trail org and installed Docusign for salesforce and Docusign setup gen in my Salesforce org and tried connecting but it is always showing error.

> Unable to setup at this time. Contact docusign support for assistance.

Expected Result - Existing PDF should be generated with fields values merged

Comment: Unable to setup at this time. Contact docusign support for assistance.

Comment: Well, to me it sounds like the next step should be contacting docusign support.

Comment: I contacted docusign support and they suggested to drop the issue here and docusign developers will be helping out with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it your DocuSign and Salesforce instances are not fully connected, I would make sure you have authorised DocuSign to send documents from Salesforce.

From there you have 2 options - DocuSign Gen - placing anchor text within your document and uploading it into your system.  Be sure to have your Microsoft Word document you're going to use for the template available before proceeding.

Open the Word document you are using for the template configuration.
On the template configuration. Click Copy to place the anchor text on the clipboard.
Go to the place in the Word document where you want to place the anchor text and
paste it.
After you have placed all the anchor text in the Word document, save it for uploading
to the template configuration.

or 
Create a merged field in salesforce for DocuSign
From the force.com apps drop-down list, select DocuSign for Salesforce.
Click the DocuSign Admin tab.
Click the Custom Tags tab.
The Custom Tags page appears
On the right, click NEW.
The Create Custom Tag page appears. There are five sections on the page where you can enter information about the custom tag: Create Custom Tag, Formatting, Input Limit, Validation, and Advanced. When you're creating custom tags, you may see only a subset of these sections depending on the tag type you're creating.